# VNC viewer connection failed -End of stream

Tags: vnc, vnc-viewer

VNC viewer unable to login getting error like

"connection failed -End of stream
Possible causes:
-Another user is already listening on this ID
-Bad connection"

when I am trying to access 1024x768 resolution.

can you please provide some more solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

I got this error from TigerVNC viewer:

```
$ vncviewer server.example.com:5991

TigerVNC Viewer 64-bit v1.5.0
Built on: ??-??-?? ??:??
Copyright (C) 1999-2015 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.

Tue Oct  4 12:54:00 2016
 CConn:       connected to host server.example.com port 5991
 CConnection: Server supports RFB protocol version 3.8
 CConnection: Using RFB protocol version 3.8
 CConnection: Choosing security type None(1)
 CConn:       End of stream
$
```

It turns out that this can mean another client is already connected, and the `-shared` flag fixes the situation:

```
$ vncviewer -shared server.example.com:5991

TigerVNC Viewer 64-bit v1.5.0
Built on: ??-??-?? ??:??
Copyright (C) 1999-2015 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.

Tue Oct  4 12:53:43 2016
 CConn:       connected to host server.example.com port 5991
 CConnection: Server supports RFB protocol version 3.8
 CConnection: Using RFB protocol version 3.8
 CConnection: Choosing security type None(1)
 X11PixelBuffer: Using default colormap and visual, TrueColor, depth 24.
 CConn:       Using pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888
 CConn:       Using Tight encoding
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this if  you restart `xinetd` service

First stop the `xinetd` service

```
   # /etc/init.d/xinetd stop
```

Next start the xinetd service

```
   # /etc/init.d/xinetd start
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was because I put the wrong IP.

I needed to use `-L 5901:localhost:5901` instead of `-L 5901:publicIp:5901`.

```
start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\KiTTY\kitty.exe" -ssh publicIp -l username -pw password -L 5901:localhost:5901
```

Answer (score -1):

My situation - no admin rights on server, UltraVNC Viewer as client (shared flag had no effect for me).

On server side I ran

```
vncserver
```

from the terminal window.

This created a new instance with higher port number, I edited my tunnel accordingly and was able to connect. 
Of course the session is brand new.